# can not change case in python

Tags: python, case, python-re

in the code below, I want to change the case of `End`, depending on the case of `openningline`.
But, it is not working, i.e. nomatter the case of `openningline`, `End` is always `End`, not `end` or `END`.

What I am doing wrong here?

```
class SyntaxElement:
    def __init__(self, openningline, closingline):
        self.openningline = openningline
        self.closingline = closingline
    def match(self, line): 
        """ Return (indent, closingline) or (None, None)"""
        match = self.openningline.search(line)
        if match:
            indentpattern = re.compile(r'^\s*')
            variablepattern = re.compile(r'\$\{(?P<varname>[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)\}')
            indent = indentpattern.search(line).group(0)
            if self.openningline.pattern.istitle():
              closingline = self.closingline.title()
            elif self.openningline.pattern.islower():
              closingline = self.closingline.lower()
            elif self.openningline.pattern.isupper():
              closingline = self.closingline.upper()
            else:
              closingline = self.closingline

            
            # expand variables in closingline
            while True:
                variable_match = variablepattern.search(closingline)
                if variable_match:
                    try:
                        replacement = match.group(variable_match.group('varname'))
                    except:
                        print("Group %s is not defined in pattern" % variable_match.group('varname'))
                        replacement = variable_match.group('varname')
                    try:
                        closingline = closingline.replace(variable_match.group(0), replacement)
                    except TypeError:
                        if replacement is None:
                            replacement = ""
                        closingline = closingline.replace(variable_match.group(0), str(replacement))
                else:
                    break
        else:
            return (None, None)
        closingline = closingline.rstrip()
        return (indent, closingline)
            
        
def fortran_complete():

    syntax_elements = [
        SyntaxElement(re.compile(r'^\s*\s*((?P<struc>([A-z0-9]*)))\s*((?P<name>([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)))', re.IGNORECASE),
                      'End ${struc} ${name}' ),
    ]
```

Comment: Can you add sample input, usage & desired output

Comment: Actually, this is a part of a bigger code, a vim plugin. So, a `mwe` is not possible. But, isnt it clear from the test?

Comment: What do you mean by "the case of openningline"? `openningline` is a pattern like `^\s*\s*((?P<struc>([A-z0-9]*)))\s*((?P<name>([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)))` it has a complex mixture of case. Do you mean the case of the string that it matches?

Comment: BTW, `A-z` is wrong. Use `A-Z` or `a-z` -- you don't need both upper and lower case because you're using `re.IGNORECASE`.

Comment: @Barmar: yes to your first comment.  For the second, you are correct. But that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Please add sample input and desired output. This is currently not following the rules for MCVE. Are we supposed to try `SyntaxElement('BEGIN','end').openningline` or what? Your `SyntaxElement` could do with a `__str__()` method or some other method, otherwise you can't automate testing it?

Comment: A tip that will seriously make your code shorter and more legible: I'd rename `closingline` `cl` and `openningline` `ol`, they occur twice on many lines.  And `variable_match` `mvar` or `mv` or something. You really don't want long and indented lines going >> 80 chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the regular expression to match anything. It should be:

```
matched = self.openningline.search(line).group(0)
if matched.istitle():
    closingline = closingline.title()
elif matched.isupper():
    closingline = closingline.upper()
elif matched.islower():
    closingline = closingline.lower()
```

Comment: It's customary to call the match object `m`, for brevity, and that'd make this code clearer and more legible. Or maybe `mo` for "match-opening-line". (And on this code, I'd rename `closingline` `cl` and `openningline` `ol`)

Comment: By the way, a minor point worth commenting: your code silently handles the (very uncommon) fourth case where the opening-line text is mixed-case, but neither title-case, nor all-upper, nor all-lower (e.g. `beGiN`). In that case it does nothing, leaves closing-line as-is.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you expect `openningline` to be a `re`.  So, when you use `self.openningline.pattern.istitle()` you are testing the regular expression pattern not the line you are trying to match with the `re`.  Most of the time the regular expressions patterns will be `False` for `istitle()`, `islower()` and `isupper()`.

I am not exactly able to understand what you are trying to do but maybe you should use `line.istitle()` and so on.

Comment: I didnt got your point. ```re.compile("Hello").pattern.istitle()
True ```